# ¿Se puede cancelar una consulta en MySQL si tarda más de 30 segundos?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Me ha pasado varias veces en mi empresa por algún error en la consulta, entonces la consulta es demasiado extensa y colapsa la base de datos y otros servicios y programas que dependen de ella.

Yo trabajo con el Framework CodeIgniter y me pregunto si es posible para evitar este problema, que ¿después de 30 segundos de ejecutar la consulta, mandar una petición a MySQL para cancelar el select anterior y liberar la BD?

Comment: Quizás este post te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673216/11819118

Comment: He probado esa solución pero no me ha funcionado, se salta la restricción de los 30 segundos.

Comment: ¿Nadie puede darme alguna solución? :(